# Can't get firebase to connect to HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on the front end for a project to display a graph of data collected from sensors. I'm following Net Ninja's youtube series on connecting to firebase, as well as trying many other approaches found online, but nothing I try works. I cannot get data from my firebase test database to display, and also can't display example data from others. I was hoping for a bit of help in what I could have missed.

```js
const dataList = document.querySelector('#data-list');

// create element & render data
function renderData(doc) {
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  let time = document.createElement('span');
  let data = document.createElement('span');

  li.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);
  time.textContent = doc.data().time;
  data.textContent = doc.data().data;

  li.appendChild(time);
  li.appendChild(data);

  dataList.appendChild(li);
}

// getting data
db.collection('sensorData').get().then(snapshot => {
  snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
    renderData(doc);
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.3/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.3/firebase-database.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

  <h1>test</h1>

  <div class="content">

    <form id="add-data-form"></form>

    <ul id="data-list"></ul>

  </div>

  <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.9.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

  <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.9.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.9.1/firebase-database.js"></script>

  <script>
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    var firebaseConfig = { **
      FIREBASE DATA **
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    firebase.analytics();
  </script>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

When I launch the index, I only see the "test" heading, no data from the firebase. I have used powershell to initialise the database, that didn't make a difference though. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: Can you show the data in your database that you're trying to display? At this point a screenshot is probably enough.

Comment: I'll point out again, since your last question, you still haven't done any error checking on the call to `get()`, so you'd never know if it was failing for some reason.